# Why do some cars fart?

Tags: exhaust

Sometimes, I'll hear Mustangs and Honda Civics "farting" and making loud noises.

What is the cause of this and why doesn't my car do it?

Comment: Are you talking about the noise made by a dump valve?  There is bound to be a video on youtube that has a recording of one?

Answer (score -1):

This can happen by few things the two most common are.

1. Hole from a rust or damaged exhaust system ( when there is a hole in your exhaust system it makes loud "farting" noises).
2. Down pipe / Straight pipe exhaust system.
   Straight pipe systems are after market exhaust system which has most mufflers and filters from the exhaust removed, so the gasses can escape quicker and you can have higher performance of your car. This is often done on turbocharged cars because they get the most performance out of such setup. Because a lot of mufflers are removed from  down pipe system they make the "farting" you hear.